# How to convert a 3x3 pixel .bmp into a 3x3 byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I am running into a dilemma, I need to convert a bitmap to a byte array, but I need a certain way I need to do it, and for the sake of demonstration these bitmaps are monochromatic, this is what I need done:

Lets say that # is a key for the RGB value of 255, 255, 255, and @ is the RGB value of 0, 0, 0.

@@@

@##

@#@

I need that converted to something like this:

0, 0, 0

0, 255, 255

0, 255, 0

Could this possible be done?

Comment: Yes, I think this can be done. What have you tried?

Comment: Ive tried this before using another stackoverflow answer, but the problem was that it was outputting the whole file to a byte answer, I just want the visible information, such as colors.

Comment: In a Bitmap there are all the pixels there are. what would be the problem?? do you have the data in a file? which format? Have you tried anything? Start with `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("yourImageFile"); for (int y.. for (int x..  Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y); if (c == Color.White)..`

Comment: Oh my god TaW THANK YOU! You saved me alot of time, plus I learned that bitmap has a getPixel function. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the bytes:

**ImageConverter**

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

**or Memory Stream**

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
{
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Close();

        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Then turn it into the multi-dimensional array that you want.

```
byte[][] multi = new byte[height][];
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    multi[y] = new byte[width];
    // Do optional translation of the byte into your own format here
    // For purpose of illustration, here is a straight copy
    Array.Copy(bitmapBytes, width * y, multi[y], 0, width);
}
```

Comment: I need to get the bytes of the visible information, such as the colors of each pixel, not the whole bitmap.

Comment: Then you'll want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format and skip the first X bytes that make up the file header.  i.e. instead of (width * y) in my example, it'll be (headerSize + (width * y)).  You may also find that Image has stripped certain parts of the file off already, so you'll need to account for that.

Comment: Turns out that bitmap has a .GetPixel function, still, thank you for your suggestion! :)